# BASH: How to calculate decimals using echo command?

Tags: bash, decimal, echo, calc

by using echo command to calculate decimals like this one below:

`$echo $((1+1+2.1))`

will produces this error below

`bash: 1+1+2.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1")`

so, what should I do in order to have the result `4.1` ?

Comment: `$(( ... ))` is not an `echo` feature, it's a shell feature. It works the same way for *every* command, not just `echo`, and completes before `echo` -- or whatever other command -- is run. That said -- that shell feature *does not support floating point* (or otherwise non-integer) *arithmetic at all*. In addition to the linked duplicate, see [BashFAQ #22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/022).

Comment: echo ((1+1)+(2.1))

Comment: @NabeelKhan, pardon? That doesn't do math in any POSIX-compliant shell. You can see what it does in bash at https://ideone.com/QeZtQh

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: @AhiungLim sorry, use this: echo "(1+1)+(2.1)" | bc -l

Comment: @NabeelKhan thanks Nabeel you code is useful, but it can be more simplify using `echo 1+1+2.1 | bc` , i was trying to see what's the `-l` option about but from what i can see is that `-l` adds more decimals for the result which has a lot of decimals.